# Need help in understanding java generics concept

Tags: java

I am trying to find the bug in the following code which I purposely screwed only to explore concept in depth.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

class typeAnimal<String> implements Iterable<String>  //// (1)
{
    ArrayList<String> listAnimal = new ArrayList<String>();
    typeAnimal(ArrayList<String> listAnimal)
    {
        this.listAnimal = listAnimal;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<String>()
        {
            int position;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if(position<listAnimal.size())
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            @Override
            public String next() 
            {
                String aniPos = listAnimal.get(position);
                position ++;
                return aniPos;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
    }
}

public class newIterator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> animalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        animalList.add("priyank");
        animalList.add("kannu");

        typeAnimal<Object> animalName= new typeAnimal(animalList);

        for(String name:animalName)     //// <-- Error
        {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String`. But if I replace `typeAnimal<String>` in (1) with `typeAnimal<Object>` the error will go away.
I know this is worth less code but still wish to know what exactly causing error.

Answer (score 1):

`class typeAnimal<String> implements Iterable<String>`

When a class has a generic parameter, it is usually called `T` or other single letter names. This makes it clear that actual instances of this class must replace that parameter with a real class.

When you call your type parameter `String`, you confuse the compiler, since there is already a `String` class in Java.

You should either define a non generic class :

`class typeAnimal implements Iterable<String>`

or a generic class :

`class typeAnimal<T> implements Iterable<T>`

The former means that your class implements an `Iterable` over the `String` class.
The latter means your class implements an `Iterable` over a generic type parameter.

Comment: Thanks Eran, but still i am not clear on the error thrown. Why is that, if i replace typeAnimal<String> in (1) with typeAnimal<Object> the Error will go away. The Error here is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String". I am unable to understand what exactly causing this error.